# Spartan Lawn Tractor

Tags: battery

I know what causes battery terminal corrosion but I've sort of got a dilemma. The long screw that holds the battery in place corroded to a concerning degree. It looked just like the positive terminal on a battery that's corroded.  I took it off, cleaned it up and found that it's almost been corroded away. It sort of looks like someone just dropped battery acid on it for the heck of it. Anyway I'll attach a picture of the screw after cleaning, it's just strange. Anyone have any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is corroded , not unusual , get a new one. A little grease will reduce corrosion. 
 A problem can occur when corrosion product on the threads make it difficult to turn the bolt/nut.

Answer (score 1):

It could be several factors and possibly a few in combination. It could be worn from vibration, stripped from overtightening, corroded by having acid spilt on it,  rusted or even electrolysis.

As mentioned by @blacksmith37 its not unusual or a big deal. Just replace it.